# ffmpeg-php - avi to flv, video length and audio

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert an .avi file to .flv using ffmpeg-php on a centos 5.4 server.

This is my code:

```
exec("ffmpeg -y -i " . $srcFile . " -ab 32 -ar 22050 -b " . $newBitrate . "k -vframes 2500 -qscale 7 -f flv -s " . $newWidth . "x" . $newHeight ." " . $destFile);
```

For some reason the video length in the new .flv file is corrupt or missing for online players unless I disable audio (with -an). The video plays but players do not show the progress correctly.

Plus I cannot change the audio bit rate and sample rate - it just will not work then - for instance when I replace the numbers with 128 / 48000 (from original .avi).

Comment: I'd say this is a problem with ffmpeg, so it belongs on serverfault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ffmpeg/+bug/216385), it's because ffmpeg does not include an mp3 encoder due to legalities.  Apparently, updating to the latest version will fix the problem.